# adding new rows based on column header

Tags: python, pandas

```
columns= ['A','B','C']
df= pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

I have a empty dataframe like above with named column header and  I have files where each file has data like A 32, B 43 , C 21 and so on. I want to fill the dataframe in such a way that each file takes up one row and adds the data in each file in the respective column headers.

example-

let there be two files like-

```
file1    file2

A 32     A 56
B 31     B 34
C 45     C 12
```

then dataframe will be

```
  'A'    'B'  'C'
  32     31    45
  56     34    12
```

edit-

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_M):
    for name in files:

        L = [pd.read_csv(f, index_col=[0], header=None, sep='\s+')[1] for f in files]
        df = pd.concat(L, axis=1).T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension for `list of DataFrame`s with `concat` and transpose:

```
#add /*.* for read all files
currentdir = 'path/*.*'

L = []
#loop by files
for file in glob.glob(currentdir):
    print (file)

    s = pd.read_csv(file, sep='|', header=None)[0]
    if (s.astype(str).str.strip().str.contains('\s+').any()):
        #print (s)
        df = s.str.rsplit(n=1, expand=True)
        df.columns = ['a','b']
        L.append(df.set_index('a')['b'])


df = pd.concat(L, axis=1, keys=range(len(L))).T
```

Comment: each line in the file is a space separated file....like word=line.split(" ") and then the word[0] is the column header and word[1] is the column value

Comment: I am fetching the file from a directory so I am using os.walk with the solution but the error is coming file not found

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - solution was changed.

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - is possible use `glob` by directory, which return list of all files?

Comment: the index column is all 1...how to make it as numbered again and fillna as 0?

Comment: try omit `index_col=[0]`

Comment: and then `df = pd.concat(L)`, but output is a bit different

Comment: `A,B,C` are values in column?

Comment: so need `df = pd.concat(L)` only? removing `axis=1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171923/discussion-between-ubuntu-noob-and-jezrael).

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - Plese check edited answer with files sent by email.